# Using a hardcoded list of integers for a join with DB2

Tags: sql, db2

So I have a DB2 query that is currently using an IN clause on ~1600 integers. 
Obviously I would like to avoid this if possible.

The only real way I can see would be to do a join on these values from a temp table. So this is where my problem comes in.

My list of 1600 integers is comma separated and there doesn't seem to be an easy way to simply set the temp table values as those comma separated values.

Am I missing something? The list of integers is dynamically generated from another process so I need to be able to insert these values on the fly without knowing the exact values or number of values I will be receiving.

Comment: Have you checked that the query execution plans differ? Why do you want to avoid the IN?

Comment: I suppose that I wanted to avoid the IN clause simply because of what I have heard from others. It seems like most people say that large IN clauses can be terrible for performance (although in reality ~1600 probably isn't THAT large).

Comment: Can you use PureXML's `XMLTABLE` to produce a synthethic table to `JOIN`

Comment: I'm sure the optimizer will do all this work for you, sticking your integers into a temp table and performing a join -- just check the query plan.